# Project fields whose value is not X

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a Mongo collection where the schema is

```
{
  _id:...
  user1: ...
  user2: ...
  date: ...
}
```

I'd like to create a query that, given a user, would return a list of all the *other* users this user has met. So far what Ive got is

```
db.collections.find({$or:[{user1: XXX}, {user2: XXX}]}, <projection>);
```

What I'de like to do is to have the projection look something like

```
{user1: $user1==XXX, user2: $user2==XXX}
```

Where`$user1/2` is the value of user 1 or 2 at that document, but I don't know how to translate that into a mongo query. Perhaps this can be done using `$where`, but I cant find the syntax for `$where` in projections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really completely clear what you mean here but [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) is not an option as it is only a JavaScript evaluation of conditions for a "query" and has nothing to do with projection.

You seem to be asking to "identify" which of the fields actually matched your condition or at least something like that. Standard query projection does not alter values present in a document in any way, but the [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method has [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) which can alter document content.

So to identify which field matched then you could do:

```js
db.collections.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "$or": [
            { "user1": "XXX" },
            { "user2": "XXX" }
        }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "matched": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$ne": [ "$user1", "XXX" ] },
                "$user2",
                "$user1"
            ]
        }
    }}
])
```

Where the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator provides a ternary ( if/then/else ) condition that evaluates a [logical comparison operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-comparison/) as the first argument and returns either the second argument where `true` or the third where `false`.

So in this case, given that `$or` can match either field then the returned value will be the field that had the value present for the match, being logical that if it was not "user1" then it must be "user2" since those are the initial query conditions.

Whatever your case you want this sort of logical evaluation to return another value that is not actually present in the document by inspecting an existing value(s) to the conditions.

Comment: From what I understand this will print out the litteral  `user1` if the value of user one is `XXX`. Thats closer to what I want, but not exactly. I want to actually print out the value of `user1` if it is not equal to `XXX`.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg No the `$` in front means the value of the field. Just a plain string would be a literal.